# Why my for loop is not iterating all the values

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

When I run this code and give input as 25 it should return me *its not a prime num*,
But when I debug the code the range values are not iterating into if condition, only the first value of the range is passed and if its not == 0 it moves to the else part.

```
def find(x):
    if x > 1:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x % i == 0:
                return "its not a prime num"
            else:
                return "Its a prime num"


user = int(input("Enter your no: "))
print(find(user))
```

Please help me why its working like this , I am new to programming . TIA

Comment: you are returning inside the loop. it will only iterate once. What you need to do is return false only if you find a divisor, otherwise let the loop iterate all values and return True at the end. Remove the else and put the `return "Its a prime num"` outside the loop. By the way you need to handle x=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a comment, this is an easy fix. Simply move the `else` statement's `return` to outside of the loop.

```
def find(x):
    if x > 1:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x % i == 0:
                return "its not a prime num"
        return "Its a prime num"


user = int(input("Enter your no: "))
print(find(user))
```

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki sorry, I added the answer before your edit mentioned what to do.

Comment: btw your code will end up printing `None` if the user enters `1`.

Comment: that matches the behavior of the OP's function. I only changed what they specified as a problem.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. Your answer is correct and has the least changes to the code of the OP to fix their problem. I was just pointing it out by prefixing with *btw*.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `return` inside of a loop will break it and exit the function even if the iteration is still not finished. use `print` instead.

Comment: Its almost never the right thing to do to use `print()` inside a low level function.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that for whatever reason for loops never run with the final value an easy fix is to just add 1 to the ending value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).